Windows 11: opening some applications taking a very long time despite sufficient resources
Despite having ample system resources, including 90GB of free space on my primary drive and 32GB of RAM, I'm experiencing significant delays when launching certain applications like Google Chrome, InkScape, sometimes GIMP, certain versions of Blender. Even lightweight programs' installation setup files, such as those for Inkscape and OBS Studio, take up to 20 minutes to initiate. These delays persist consistently after system boot-up, prompting me to avoid shutting down to minimize wait times. I'm seeking advice on resolving these issues and optimizing the installation process. From my experience it seems to be an OS problem.
Device name: User
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz   3.90 GHz
Installed RAM: 32.0 GB (31.5 GB usable)
System type: 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Edition: Windows 11 Pro
Version: 22H2
Installed on 6/17/2023
OS build: 22621.3447
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22688.1000.0

Drive C: Samsung SSD 840 PRO Series
Drive D: WDC WD2002FAEX-007BA0

BaseBoard Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
BaseBoard Product: Z77X-UP7
BaseBoard Version: x.x

msinfo32 system summary:

OS Name: Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Version: 10.0.22621 Build 22621
BIOS Mode: UEFI
BIOS Version/Date: American Megatrends Inc. F4, 8/30/2012
SMBIOS Version: 2.7
Embedded Controller Version: 255.255
Boot Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume2
Total Physical Memory: 31.5 GB
Available Physical Memory: 26.2 GB
Available Virtual Memory: 29.5 GB
Page File Space: 4.81 GB
Page File: C:\pagefile.sys
Virtualization-based security: Running

Notice in Task Manager that the CPU isn't even a bottleneck, but yet it says 0% usage for most of the time for Blender and Chrome for example:

I may have a few errors but it says "No action needed" and I have enough disk space available.

Also tried dfrgui.exe and it is OK:

Applications are installed on SSD. I only use the HDD for external storage although I previously had steam installed on my HDD but I'm not using it anymore. Maybe it's because my 2015 setup is not designed for Windows 11. I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time. Any ideas?
I tried the suggestion by @John with DISM.exe and it did help a lot now my Chrome and Inkscape open way quicker. Thank you soo much! But Blender 2.93 up to 3.4 still take very long time to open. Maybe because they are the hacked versions that were designed for Windows 7 because the installed versions 3.5 to 4.1 all load faster. Generally his solution is the answer I think. Please add as answer and I will accept.

Are you installing these applications to the SSD or the HDD?

I had similar symptoms on an SSD that was too old to support TRIM. Your 840 Pro supports it, but it might still be good to check that trimming is happening in dfrgui.exe (SSD current status should say "OK (n days since last retrim)". Separately, I'd want to rule out antivirus as a potential performance drain.

@John your suggestion did help a lot now my Chrome and Inkscape open way quicker. Thank you soo much! But Blender 2.93 up to 3.4 still take very long time to open. Maybe because they are the hacked versions that were designed for Windows 7 but I think generally your solution is the answer I think.

@HarryMcKenzie - Those patches to Blender are only applicable if you’re running it on Windows 7. Stop running incompatible patched software.

@Ramhound yes. I previously was on Windows 7 when I had them downloaded on my D drive that's why I still had them. But the problem with Chrome and Inkscape and other software running quickly now were fixed by John's suggestion.

Two other sources of delay: 1. When Windows boots or emerges from hibernation, it scans system file.. For about ten minutes afterwards, I find Windows PC's are far slower than they should be. 2. After a restart, DLL's are unloaded. The first time an app is run afterwards, it takes quite a bit longer for it to start. The workaround is to use Sleep, which avoids the rescan of system files and the reloading of DLL's -- but the down-side is that the PC is on continuously, albeit at greatly reduced power.

I have the same problem, but it doesn't apply to UWP apps for some reason. Also, there is no delay if I open files via One Commander, Files (UWP) and other third-party file explorers, so the problem is present only when opening apps and files via the taskbar and Windows File Explorer. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a solution to this spontaneous problem. Try using PowerToys Run and third-party file explorers as workaround to minimize the problem.
Update. I was finally able to solve the problem. The culprit of delay turned out to be an virus (Trojan.Multi.BroSubsc.gen), which was tracked using free Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool, which scanned threats from a running home system while the browser was open.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I was finally able to solve the problem. The culprit of delay turned out to be an virus (Trojan.Multi.BroSubsc.gen), which was tracked using free Kaspersky Virus Removal Tool, which scanned threats from a running home system while the browser was open.

@VladLoktionov thanks for the update! I did some search on my C:/ drive but it couldn't find any Trojan.Multi.BroSubsc.gen file
